# Loading a Custom UITableViewCell from nib to a UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I'm currently working on an exercise swift program, one that requires CoreData results to be displayed on a table.

I've structured my app such that the storyboard itself doesn't contain any UI elements, only views (with an accompanying `UIViewController` class), which then loads custom nibs / xibs (also accompanied by a `UIView` Subclass). In this case, the xib contains a `UITableView`, and a separate xib contains the cell.

**TableView Class**:

```
import UIKit

protocol SkillsViewDelegate{
}

class SkillsView: UIView {
    var delegate : SkillsViewDelegate!
    @IBOutlet weak var skillsTable: UITableView!
}
```

**TableView Controller**:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SkillsViewController: UIViewController, SkillsViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var displaySkillsView : SkillsView!
    var displaySkillsCell : SkillViewCell!
    let textCellIdentifier = "skillViewCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.displaySkillsView = UIView.loadFromNibNamed("SkillsView") as! SkillsView
        self.displaySkillsView.delegate = self
        self.view = self.displaySkillsView
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK : -Table view delegates

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}
```

**TableCellView Class**:

```
import UIKit

protocol SkillsViewCellDelegate{
}

class SkillViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate : SkillsViewCellDelegate!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
   }

    @IBOutlet weak var skillName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var skillRank: UILabel!
}
```

I can't figure out how to call the cell xib into the controller. I would guess it's something [like this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift), but the difference is the guy is using a `UITableViewController`. I tried adding that as well, but I get a `Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'UITableViewController'` for my troubles.

**What I Tried**:
I tried adding `UITableViewController` up top, but I get a `Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'UITableViewController'` for my troubles.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just register your SkillsViewCell in your SkillsViewController

**Obj C**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
   [self.skillsTable registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:textCellIdentifier];
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let nibName = UINib(nibName: "NibName", bundle:nil)
   self.skillsTable.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: textCellIdentifier)
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let nibName = UINib(nibName: "NibName", bundle:nil)
   self.skillsTable.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: textCellIdentifier)
}
```

Then only inherit from UIViewController not UITableViewController

To call methods specific to your custom cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SkillViewCell

    cell.skillName.text = "Some text"
    cell.skillRank.text = "Some text"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I actually tried the latter already (apologies for not mentioning it), but I get an error saying `Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView'`.

Comment: You can change self.tableView to self.skillsTable

Comment: Ah, gotcha. How do I call the `skillName` and `skillRank` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? So far, I've got this in there: `let cell = self.displaySkillsView.skillsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: Thanks. The cells still aren't appearing, though. The table is definitely there, coloured grey. Perhaps something with the delegates?

Comment: Ah, got it. I did forget to set the delegates and datasource.

Comment: Where to call registerNib when the table is inside a Custom UIView? awakeFromNib is called after tableview delegates which results in an error

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use

```
func registerNib(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

in `viewDidLoad`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: