# iOS reuse table cells design

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm building a youtube like app to train myself to Swift and Autolayout.

But I'm facing a problem, in multiple places I need to display a table of videos, then what I want to do is to design one video's cell that I'll reuse in other tables but I don't see how to do that.

I tried to put a ContainerView in a cell be I got this error "Container Views cannot be placed in elements that are repeated at runtime."

PS : I already thought of a ContainerView referencing a TableViewController of videos, but the problem is that Videos are not the only cells that I want to have in my differents tables. ( Sometimes there is comments at the bottom, sometimes other things etc. Shortly: The tables will have different types of cells ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a separate xib file to create reusable table cells. So you create CustomTableViewCell.swift and CustomTableViewCell.xib.  To use your custom cell, you need to register it in the `UITableViewDataSource`.

[This stackoverflow answer may be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25545185/6543020).

```
 import UIKit
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let items = ["Item 1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomOneCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellOne")
    }

 // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomOneCell
        cell.middleLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.leftLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.rightLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
 }
```