# Share custom UITableViewCell to multiple UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently, I have two table view controllers which contain some identical custom tableview cells. Each table view controller has its own custom tableview cells. I'm wishing to create only **one custom table view cell** which can be **shared** among these **two table view controllers**. Any guides can I refer to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you can create a `UITableViewCell` with code: (and you can design your cell view in a `.xib` file - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25545185/2603230) for detail)

```
// MyCell.Swift

import UIKit
import Foundation

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    // do whatever you want to customize the cell
}
```

Then in each of your two `UITableViewController`'s classes, register your custom `UITableViewCell` class in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.register(MyCell.self as AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

Then create/reuse this custom cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: MyCell? = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? MyCell
    if cell == nil {
        // if the cell is not yet created in the system, create a new cell object
        cell = MyCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    // customize your cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Your Label Text"

    return cell!
}
```