# How can I display multiple string values to multiple labels in a custom TableView Cell in swift ios?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

```
var leadername = ["1","2","3","4"]

var districts = ["Delhi","Kerala"]

override func viewDidLoad() {

    leadTableSetup()
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func leadTableSetup(){

    LeadTableView.delegate = self
    LeadTableView.dataSource = self

    self.LeadTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LeaderBoardTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "leadCell")   
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 14

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leadCell") as! LeaderBoardTableViewCell
    // Set text from the data model
    cell.areaLbl.text = districts[indexPath.row]
    cell.leaderNameLbl.text = leadername[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I have declared two strings and I need to display these strings in the labels in my custom collection view cell that I have created. How can I achieve this? I need to display "leadername" string in one label and "districts" label in another label.

Comment: can you show `LeaderBoardTableViewCell`

Comment: [Sample](https://www.credera.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Custom-Collection-Views-1.png) I think you need output something like this. Two label in each cell , but there values is accroding to the array value. Right? @Rakesh

Comment: Go with this demo, and try to study some basics about this i.e. How tableView works and how you maintain the UITableViewCell either custom or fromXib. Because you can do lots of stuff with tableView. so my suggestion is first learn basics otherwise you always stuck. [Shared demo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift) After the demo, If you still face any problem then let me know.

Comment: @TinuDahiya. Exactly

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski class LeaderBoardTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    IBOutlet weak var approvalLabel: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var areaLbl: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var leaderNameLbl: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

Comment: @Rakesh please edit your question to past `LeaderBoardTableViewCell` code, and change tags from uicollectionviewcell to uitableviewcell

Comment: @Rakesh you need to display these texts in the same cell or in different

Comment: @Rakesh Now, I edited my answer according to UITableView and my last answer is according to the UICollectionView. Check it out

Comment: @TinuDahiya. I missed it. Can you once again edit it please?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski I have to display all the array values in the cell.

Comment: @Rakesh I shared a demo. **Suggestion for you :**  Try to study some basics about UITableView i.e. How UITableView works and how to you maintain the UITableViewCell either custom or from Xib. Because you can do lots of stuff with tableView. so my suggestion is first learn basics otherwise you always stuck. If you still have any doubt then ask freely, but make a habit to search answer rather then posting, it improves your skills.

Comment: @TinuDahiya Thanks a lot for the demo that you have shared. I am quite familiar with the tableview properties. But I  am not able to understand how to display multiple strings in the cell. I have checked for the references but I am not getting what I really need. Please help

Comment: What output you are expecting and what output you are getting, share screen shot with little description then i will check it out, dont worry.

Comment: @TinuDahiya See I have to array strings "Leadername" and "districts". I have to display Leadername to leaderName label in the cell and districts to areaLabel in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with this demo,  [Shared Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift)

After the demo, If you still face any problem then let me know.

**Now Listen Here**

I think you need output something like this,
[image: Expected To your need]

**Follow the steps: -**

1. Create a new viewcontroller(says, CustomTableVC) in your storyboard and one UITableView(give constraints and delegate to its own class), take outlet of UItableView (says, tblMyCustom)
2. Now press CLT+N for new file and do like this below image, Subclass - UItableViewCell and also tick on XIB option.

[image]

3. Open our xib file, add new UIView (says myView, as you see highted in below image), in this myView add two labels
   [image: Xib cell]
4. Now take outlet of these two labels in its customCell class

   class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell {

   ```
   @IBOutlet var lblLeaderNo: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet var lblDistict: UILabel!


   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       // Initialization code
   }

   override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
       super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

       // Configure the view for the selected state
   }
   ```

   }
5. Now back to your Viewcontroller Class

   ```
   import UIKit

   class CustomTableVC: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
   ```

@IBOutlet var tblMyCustom: UITableView!

var leaderno : [String]!

var distict  : [String]!

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.tblMyCustom.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")

        self.leaderno = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
        self.distict = ["Delhi","Kerala", "Haryana", "Punjab"]
        // above both array must have same count otherwise, label text in null

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return leaderno.count;
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var customCell: CustomTableCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as? CustomTableCell

        customCell.lblLeaderNo.text = self.leaderno[indexPath.row]
        customCell.lblDistict.text = self.distict[indexPath.row]

        return customCell
    }
}
```

above all is code of VC, it is not getting settle down here in single code format, I dont know why.

Now, follow these steps you get output as i show you image in starting of the procedure.

Comment: Then how do you attach outlets to a table view cell when you designed your custom cell in storyboards.

I am have the same problem here, and the solution would work for me, however I am unable to attach the different outlets to my table view cell (which is a separate document from the tableview controller).

Comment: @LEKYSMA , You attach outlets in cell file as same like you do. Nothing different. You can also achieve same result w/o XIB . Still have issue then specify exact issue point for better assistance.