# iOS - UITableViewCell in different Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I want to use a `UITableViewController` which has four different type complex cell. Different team members are required to work on different custom `UITableViewCell` simultaneously. We are working on Git so to avoid conflicts I have been asked to make four different `Storyboards` for four different cell. But I cannot place a cell or simple UIView in different `Storyboard` without view controller. Please guide me, how do i implement it.

> Please keep in mind that cells will be instantiated and added on
>   runtime

Comment: Create xib with your cell, and register it in your tableView

Comment: Is it possible inside different storyboard. We are usually avoiding Xibs. @AdrianBobrowski

Comment: Nothing wrong with using 4 xibs, if you dont want use xib, just create it straight away in your viewcontroller's tableview

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Yes it is possible, but  Will you remember to change at any storyboard, if it will change the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create xib of your each cell, and register it in your `UITableView` , you can use this xib anywhere in your project and with the same `CellIdentifier`.

[How to Make UITableVIewCEll XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift)