# Duplicate section or section header in table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have Xcode 8 and swift 3 and I am experiencing an error with my table view. So everything is working as I please with my table view EXCEPT every time I run my program there is an extra section or section header at the top. And in the debugger it is shown as two separate table views and I am confused as to why. Below is my code and attached are screenshots of my program. In the program you can see the top of the table view cell is duplicated.

```
-Table View Controller code-
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    var items = ["post1", "post2", "post3"]
    var hidden: [Bool] = [true, true]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var newLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //hide the navigation bar
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    //register nib
       self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TextViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TxtViewCel")

        //set delegates
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        //configure row height
        tableView?.estimatedRowHeight = 300
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 384

        //add tap gesture to dismiss keyboard on click outside
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.hideKeyboard))
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    }

    func hideKeyboard(){
        tableView.endEditing(true)
    }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 384
    }



     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }


      func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //configure rows in section. Rows are invisible when section is not clicked
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if hidden[section] {
            return 0
        } else {
            return items.count
        }
    }

    //cell for row at index path method
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TxtViewCel", for: indexPath) as! TextViewCell

        cell.tView?.text = items[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }

    //height for header in section
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30
    }

    //view for header in section along with tap gesture to hide rows when section is not clicked
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.text = "Click to See the News"
        label.textColor = UIColor.blue
        label.tag = section

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapFunction))
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        return label
    }

    //function for tap gesture
    func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let section = sender.view!.tag
        let indexPaths = (0..<3).map { i in return IndexPath(item: i, section: section)  }

        hidden[section] = !hidden[section]

        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        if hidden[section] {
            tableView?.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        } else {
            tableView?.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        }
        tableView?.endUpdates()
    }

    //did select Row at method (not functioning for some reason)
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("hello")
        let vc = EditTableViewController()
        //let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "id") as! EditTableViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
}

extension UIViewController {

    func showAlert(message: String, title: String = "") {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

-Table View Cell code-
import UIKit

class TextViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate

{

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var tView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewCell: UIView!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }


/*
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
 */

    func configure(texts: String?){
        tView.text = texts
        tView.textColor = UIColor.green
        tView.accessibilityValue = texts
    }
```

}[image: Debugger Error]

[image: Table View When Ran]

Comment: Can you please show the "Document Outline" section in your interface builder?

Comment: You may check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift

Comment: The problem because of tap gesture. It keeps your labels alive every time. Try to use button styled as you need instead label with tap gesture.

Comment: Using a button instead of a label did not correct my issue although it was a good suggestion. Neither did the above link