# ERROR : registering a custom tableView cell in swift with an xib file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib, ios11

I have checked all identifiers name and also checked the its class' name and all. Below is my code and error.

```
class StoreInfoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var store : StoreInfo = StoreInfo()

@IBOutlet weak var storeInfoTable: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    storeInfoTable.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomStoreInfoTableOneViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "storeinfocell1")

    storeInfoTable.delegate = self
    storeInfoTable.dataSource = self


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = storeInfoTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "storeinfocell1", for: indexPath) as! CustomStoreInfoTableOneViewCell

    cell.storeInfoImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: (store.imageurl)), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "r1"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload], completed: nil)

    cell.storeinfoName.text = store.storename

}
```

}

[Here's the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW3qU.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UITableViewCell from nib in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registered your nib with `( :forCellWithReuseIdentifier)` but your need to register your nib with `( : forCellReuseIdentifier)`. Please change your register line with this.

```
storeInfoTable.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomStoreInfoTableOneViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "storeinfocell1")
```

Comment: Can you explain this please?

Comment: (  :forCellWithReuseIdentifier) is use to  register for collection view cell

Answer (score 1):

You write wrong `syntax`

```
  self. storeInfoTable.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomStoreInfoTableOneViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "storeinfocell1")
```