# Add time, date and title to UITable cell view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datetime

I have a table cell view with, currently a date and title. But I want to add the current time to it as well, but I cant seem to add another section in the cell. Can someone show me how?

Here is my cellForRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath)

    let contact = userInput[indexPath.row]

    cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = contact.value(forKey:"thf") as? String
    cell.textLabel?.text = contact.value(forKey:"date") as? String

    return cell
}
```

I dont mind adding the time anywhere but preferably somewhere noticeable

[Here is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDUFF.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UITableViewCell from nib in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift)

Comment: What you need is a custom table view cell, you can add your own UI elements to the view of the cell. There are plenty of resources once you know what you are looking for a quick google search for "custom uitableviewcell swift "  will yield many useful results.

Comment: Why not put both the date and time in the text label? No need to customize the cell if that's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all write the below code into your date Extension

   ```
   extension Date {
       func getFormattedDate(format: String) -> String {
           let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
           dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
           let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: self)
           return strDate
       }

       func getTimeStamp() -> String {
           let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
           dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
           let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: self)
           return dateString
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now use date methods as I have used below:

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath)
       let contact = userInput[indexPath.row]
       cell.yourDateLabel?.text = (contact.value(forKey:"keyforDate") as? Date).getFormattedDate(format: "MMM dd,yyyy")
       cell.yourTimeLabel?.text = (contact.value(forKey:"keyforDate") as? Date).getTimeStamp()
       return cell    
   }
   ```

Comment: Make sure the data type of value for key is Date