# how to create same design like swiggy app payments screen in swift 4?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have already tried with `UITableview` expand collapse but does not got effect like Swiggy payments wallet design screen. We need  to create same design wallet design like Swiggy food delivery app in objective-c.

[image]

Comment: Maybe, you should try doing similar thing with `UIScrollView`.

Comment: @NikhilManapure - thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's very basic question to start with but I would suggest learn more about the `UITableView` using default and custom cell you can achieve the same layout. Please do home work before asking such a simple question. If you want to learn then read and code. If facing issue while implementing then do come here with question.

https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/
[Custom UITableViewCell from nib in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift)

Comment: Before giving downvote if you mention the reason then that would really help to learn.