# UITableViewCell is wider than its UITableView - extending to the right?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

**Background**

I have a `UITableView` with a single cell. Inside the cell is a `UILabel`. The cell, called `PickerTableViewCell`, gets its UI from a xib and adds it to its subview. This is done because this xib is used by many different custom cells.

**Problem**

It appears that when this cell is dequeued by the table view, its width extends beyond the table views width on the right hand side.

Here is the xib with the `UILabel` centred within the cell, followed by how it appears on the device. Notice how the label is off-centre on the device:

[image: centred xib]
[image: centred device]

When I move the label to the very right of the cell (`label.trailing = pickerCell.trailing + 0`), it disappears off the right hand side. Below is how that looks in the xib followed by how it appears on the device:

[image: right xib] 
[image: right device]

When I align the `UILabel` to the left of the cell (`label.leading = pickerCell.leading + 0`), it correctly aligns to the left on the device.

Here is how the `PickerTableViewCell` loads the xib:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


        // load the xib to associate with
        let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PickerTableViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil)
        if let view = nib?.first as? UIView{
            self.addSubview(view)
        }
    // ...
}
```

Here is how the tableview registers the cell:

```
self.tableView.register(PickerTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "pickerCell")
```

And finally here is how it is dequeued:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pickerCell") as! PickerTableViewCell
        return cell
}
```

Could anyone help understand what is going on?? Why is my cell seeming to extend beyond the width of the table view?

Comment: Use constraints of label: _top, bottom, leading , trailing_ =  **0** with superview and do `myLabel.textAlignment = .center`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While assigning any `xib`, you have to specify the `frame`. Here is the modified code:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // load the xib to associate with
    let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PickerTableViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil)
    if let view = nib?.first as? UIView{
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = bounds //Provide the frame
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Disagreed, here is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift) where SO's loading cell from XIB but none was giving frame to the cell and it is understandable **WHY**.

Comment: This solved it perfectly! I was pulling my hair out over this - THANK YOU!

Comment: @dahiya_boy I don't think so, try in your case and let me know ;) I am here to know your answer :D

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Its nice if it is working but never seen issue like this. Every time I made cell xib, all I have to do is to register it and then dequeue. For size, it automatically loads but I have to use `heightForRow` for cell height.

Comment: @dahiya_boy You are talking about different case, checkout the below answer in that no `frame` is needed but when you are initialising in `UITableViewCell` class it's must else how it will know where to sit and also you can't give the constraint to `UITableViewCell` main view. Let me know for more concern, I will be happy to help :)

Comment: @SohilR.Memon, OP loading cell in little bit different way. I need little more clearance for my domain. In  `self.addSubview(view)`, what is **self** and **view** ??

Comment: @dahiya_boy `self` is itself a `UITableViewCell` custom class and `view` is `UIView` which is actually a `contentView` of `nib` which we have designed in `Bundle`. Let me know, I have answered your question ;)

Comment: @SohilR.Memon,  I directly load XIB and register it. I never done this practice (adding as a subview) as it is never required and I dont think it is a good practice bcz your xib is of `UITableviewCell`, when you use `nib?.first` it gives the cell itself as a UIView so why it needed to add as a subview.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I don't think so it's a good or not but depends on requirement and also Apple doesn't specifies it's wrong or right, so depending on your convinience you can go. Also, `UITableViewCell` itself inherits `UIView`, pls check :)

Comment: @SohilR.Memon, I already mentioned cell itself a `UIView` and OP adding a view from nib into it & which is somewhere undigestible for me. Rest, everyone have their own code-of-style so I can't commit anymore. BTW thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using Nib for cell design, don't register the cell class itself, register the nib instead.

Remove the code

```
init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

And the registration process would be like

```
let cellNib = UINib.init(nibName: "YourNibName", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Identifier")
```

Dequeue process is okay.